# Create text file with Javascript in Cordova for android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to create a text file for a backup. In this backup I only want so save a JSON.
Cordova file plugin is already installed.
I already tried many codes but I can't find the mistake.

HTML:

```html
    <body onload="init()">

    <section class="head">
        <div class="head-img">
            <img src="src/img/bag.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Suchen...">
            <img src="src/img/lupe.png">
        </div>
        <div class="backup-container">
            <button onclick="createBackup()" class="btn">Backup erstellen</button>
            <label for="upload" class="btn">Backup importieren</label>
            <input type="file" class="hidden" id="upload" onclick="loadBackup()">
        </div>
    </section>
```

JS:

```js
function createBackup() {

    let backup = JSON.stringify(bags);

    //get the file system object
    let fileSystem = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    
    //create the file
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSystem, function(directoryEntry) {
        directoryEntry.getFile("demo.txt", {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    
            //write the data to the file
            fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.write(backup);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error creating writer: " + error);
            });
    
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error creating file: " + error);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting file system: " + error);
    });
    
  }
```

The bags variable is in another js file but i think it's not important to solve the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This Code should be run as Applikationen on a Android Phone. When I click on the button 'backup' the function createBackup() will be activated. I want to create a text file with the content of the application, which is saved in a array. This file must be downloaded. But when I click on the button, nothing happens.